# Ionic tab top bar seen differently in ionic phone app and Google Chrome inspector used for developement

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic-view

In My ionic I have bottom tabs as well as top tabs after the header bar. However I see the output differently in Google Chrome and the Ionic Iphone App.
Attaching screenshots of how it looks on Google Chrome (as intended) and on the Inoic Phone app

[On Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLGrC.jpg)

[On Ionic Iphone App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Wva.jpg)

Here is the 1st Tab's HTML Code:

```
<ion-view view-title="TAB 1">

<ion-content >
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-top tabs-icon-top has-header">
        <ion-tab title="Tab1" icon-on="ion-heart" icon-off="ion-heart">
            <!-- Tab 1 content -->
            <div class="padding" >
                <h2 class="title ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametr adipiscing elit</h2>
                <p></p>
                <ion-scroll direction="x" class="item " style="padding:5px">
                    <button data-ng-repeat="item in recent|filter:{tag:'!!'}" class="horizontaList button" ng-click="addFromRecent(item.id, 'tag');">
                        {{item.tag}}
                    </button>      
                </ion-scroll>
```

Here is index.html code:

```
<body data-ng-app="starter">
<ion-side-menus>

    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content="">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar">
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon  ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>  
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header "></ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content has-header="true">
            <div class="list">

                <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
                    <i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i>
                    Home

                </a>

                <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
                    <i class="icon ion-log-out"></i>
                    Log out

                </a>


            </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `has-header` class is wrong on `<ion-tabs>`. Quote from the [ionic blog:](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-framework-beta-released/)

> The beta has also removed the requirement for the developer to
>   manually tell the content to reposition itself if there is a header,
>   footer, or tabbar present. Resultantly, the has-header, has-footer,
>   and has-tabs attributes have been removed. Ionic now will
>   automatically reposition and resize the content depending on what
>   surrounding widgets are present. If any old alpha code references
>   these attributes or classnames they can be safely removed since
>   they’re no longer being used by the framework.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but even after removing the has header file, I dont see any different in Chrome or Ionic App. Not sure what the disconnect is between Chroms and Inonic. I have also tried this in different browser and it's different in each and does not resamble what I see in the Ionic App

Comment: from my experience it is a wrong use of your ionic elements. when you are using it in ways it is not meant to be used your display will be differenet in different browser. I would do: 1. update everything to latest versions, 2. double check the order and names and classes of your used elements